# What are the Ramps pins on my Arduino mega?

Tags: arduino-mega, hardware

I've been working on a 3D printer and I've come to the last step, which is wiring it all up.

The 3D printer I'm making works ONLY with the Arduino Mega. No Ramps. If I need to get Ramps later, I will, but for now, can someone please help me understand which of the Ramps pin goes with which Arduino pin. For example, in the Repetier firmware, the code is like this:

```
#define X_STEP_PIN         54
#define X_DIR_PIN          55
#define X_ENABLE_PIN       38
#define X_MIN_PIN           3
#define X_MAX_PIN           2
```

But Arduino doesn't have a 54 and a 55 pin. I've been googling this and I found that Ramps pins 54 - 69  are the same as pins A0 - A15 on the Arduino Mega.

I know this but not for the other pins...

Can someone please tell me the connection of all the Ramps pins to the Arduino pins?

Like: pin 54 on Ramps = A0 on Arduino. I need this for all of the pins.

Comment: As explained in schematic, we have Rx and Tx pin and d2* and d3*. If we check in arduino mega pin outs, Rx is D2 pin. this creates the confusion, please explain me the difference between D2 and D2*

Answer (score 1):

You are right, your have all the information in your question.

Pin 54 Refers to the Arduino PIN Number, nothing to do with RAMPS.
0-53 are the digital pins and the 54 is A0, etc.
So the pin numbers should go higher than 69, which is A15.

Answer (score 0):

You're very close to your answer.  Here are the specifics:

```
Name      software pin  Mega2560 board label
X_STEP_PIN    54         Analog A0
X_DIR_PIN     55         Analog A1
X_ENABLE_PIN  38         Digital 38
X_MIN_PIN     3          PWM 3
X_MAX_PIN     2          PWM 2
```

http://reprap.org/mediawiki/images/3/3f/Arduinomegapololushieldschematic.png shows the mapping.

Comment: thanks,
but when I insert the pins for the X axis directly on the mega, I doesnt work. I'm using a driver.